# Cannot round float to integer using jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

Have issues trying to get the jina2 template to perform a rounding. I don't really mind what happens, as all my numbers have been produced by multiplying a decimal less then 1 (e.g. `0.31`) then multiplied by `100`. So I have `31.0`. I want to drop the decimal place, but nothing appears to work:

```
{{row.score.combined*100|float|round(0, 'floor')}}
```

or even the more easy:

```
{{row.score.combined*100|int}}
```

or even:

```
{{row.score.combined*100|round|int}}
```

I still get 31.0 in all cases.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Requires brackets around the multiplication. Rounding was only occurring on the 100.

```
{{(row.score.combined*100)|int}}
```