# Round a float to an int within jinja2

Tags: flask, jinja2

I am trying to create a rating (stars) ui within my app. All of my 'ratings' come in as `float`. I want to round that rating to make it an integer and display that many stars. I can't seem to figure out how to get jinja to like it.

Example Ratings: `3.0`, `2.3`, `5.0`, `4.6`, etc...

**Fails because with `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`**

```
{% if book.average_score %}
  {% for s in range(book.average_score) %}
     <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I thought I could just use `math`:

```
{% if book.average_score %}
  {% for s in range(math.ceil(book.average_score)) %}
     <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

But, this results in `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'math' is undefined`. I'm assuming this is because I'm using **Flask** and the template has no idea about the `math` library.

I then was playing around with `round`:

```
{% if book.average_score %}
  {% for s in range(round(book.average_score)) %}
     <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

But then I end up with `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'round' is undefined`

I did some more variations of using `round` following [the round documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) but no success. I know in Angular, you have `pipes` that really help with these sort of things. Does jinja have something similar or am I just way off the mark here?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45926231/cannot-round-float-to-integer-using-jinja2) SOF thread seems to be the closest thing I can find to the problem I'm trying to solve. Doesn't seem to get me too much further, however.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using Jinja, but you've linked to Python function documentation.  Jinja != Python: you need to use [filters](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters) or object methods when working with Jinja expressions.  So, for example, you could use the [int](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#int) filter:

```
{% if book.average_score %}
  {% for s in range(book.average_score|int) %}
     <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Or the [round](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#round) filter:

```
{% if book.average_score %}
  {% for s in range(book.average_score|round) %}
     <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

You can control the behavior of the `round` filter with the `method` parameter, which can be either `common` (the default), `floor`, or `ceil`:

```
{% if book.average_score %}
  {% for s in range(book.average_score|round(method='ceil')) %}
     <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

**Update**

It looks like since this was written that the `round` filter may have changed. Looking at [the documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.round), the `mode` parameter doesn't exist, but there is a `method` parameter. The following work:

- Specify a precision and a method; no keyword args required:

  ```
  >>> t = jinja2.Template("Value: {{ value|round(2, 'ceil') }}")
  >>> print(t.render(value=4.1234))
  Value: 4.13
  ```
- Specify just a rounding method; use the `method` keyword:

  ```
  >>> t = jinja2.Template("Value: {{ value|round(method='ceil') }}")
  >>> print(t.render(value=4.1234))
  Value: 5.0
  ```

I've updated the original part of the answer to reflect this change.

Comment: so this didn't work for decimal type.. had to use this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48727177/2048229

Comment: `...|int)` worked just ok for me for decimal type (float type from sqlite table), as a result I got int in rendered template by jinja

Comment: TypeError: do_round() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mode'

Comment: @HarshaBiyani thanks, it looks as if the syntax may have changed. I've updated the answer to include examples that work with the current release.